# Generating random Vectors in R

Tags: r, loops, random

I am concerned with the following programming exercise in R:

1. Generate 10.000 4 dimensional vectors.
2. The components of the vector are generated from Bernoulli distribution with probability 0.5.
3. Detect all vectors with at least 3 '1'.

In order to generate one such sample I employ

```
sample(0:1, 4, replace = TRUE)
```

In order to generate vectors I use

```
x <- c(sample(0:1, 4, replace = TRUE))
```

Since I need 10.000 vectors, I use a `for` loop:

```
for(i in 1:10000){c(sample(0:1, 4, replace = TRUE))}
```

So, now I have 10.000 vectors. 
In order to continue with the task, I should put all of the into a list.
Then, using a suitable `if` condition, I think it should be possible to conclude the task.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Look at `?replicate`

Comment: Sorry, but I am really not able to apply your hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MarcoSandri's solution will be faster, but you could modify your solution this way to make it work

```
num = 0

for(i in 1:10000){
  x = c(sample(0:1, 4, replace = TRUE))

  if(sum(x) >= 3){
    num = num + 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution for your problem:

```
set.seed(135)
n <- 10000
X <- matrix(rbinom(4*n, size=1, prob=0.5), nrow=n)
apply(X, 1, function(x) sum(x)>2)
```

Comment: I appreciate your proposal, but I am forced to use `sample` .

Comment: @Xarrus This answer has done 95% of the work for you. I think probably you can supply the remaining 5% in swapping out `rbinom` for `sample`.

Comment: You can replace the loop (i.e., `apply`) just by `rowSums(X)>2`.